# Getting the total number of items in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my html:

```
<label id='custom'></label>
<p>test</p>
<label id='start_date[0]'></label>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>
<label id='start_date[1]'></label>
<label id='start_date[2]'></label>
<p>test</p>
<label id='custom2'></label>
```

I want to get the total number of labels, which has the id of this format:
`start_date[i]`. How can I do that? Can you give some idea? Thanks.

Comment: Are they always `<label>`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the 'attribute begins with' selector and the `length` property:

```js
var itemCount = $('label[id^="start_date"]').length;
alert(itemCount);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id='custom'></label>
<p>test</p>

<label id='start_date[0]'></label>
<p>test</p>
<p>test</p>

<label id='start_date[1]'></label>

<label id='start_date[2]'></label>
<p>test</p>

<label id='custom2'></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [attribute contains](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector like

```
$('[id*="start_date"]').length
```

If you want it to explicitly start with `start_date`, use the [attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) `^` instead of `*`

```
$('[id^="start_date"]').length
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Attribute Starts With Selector [name^=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and then get `length` propert

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
 $('label[id^="start_date"]').length
```